# logstash http filter http_request_failure

Tags: http, post, filter, logstash, elk

I am using logstash http filter to post some data and i keep getting http_request_failure without any status code, I want to know where my error is.
Here is my  filter from the configuration file:

```
filter{
  if "file"  in [tags] {
     csv { 
     columns => ["MATNR", "MAKTX", "STPRS", "LOCATION","VERSION","MATERIALTYPE", "ECCN",                     "KONDM", "LIST_PRICE"]
    separator => ";"

      }
      mutate {
        gsub => ["LIST_PRICE", "," , ".",
             "STPRS", ",", "." ,
         "MAKTX", " ", "_"]

  } 
  http{
    url => "https://example.com"
    verb => "POST"
    body => {
      "active" => "true"
      "materialNo" => "%{MATNR}"
      "version" => "%{VERSION}"
      "materialType" => "%{MATERIALTYPE}"
      "description" => "%{MAKTX}"
      "lineCost" => "%{STPRS}"
      "location" => "%{LOCATION}"
      "LIST_PRICE" => "%{LIST_PRICE}"
      "`your text``your text`KON`your text`D`your text`M" => "%{KONDM}"
      "``ECCN" => "%{ECCN}"
 

    }
    target_body => "[body]"
    headers => {
`   your text`"oidc_claim_preferred_username" => "my.name"
    }

    }


}
}
```

Can you please provide me some help.

Comment: By looking at logs i found this error: client_error=>"undefined method `encoding' for #<Hash:0x574b1ba2>"